# How does one handle big library dependencies in source control?

Tags: version-control, project-management, dependencies

My C++ application depends on Boost. I'd like someone to just be able to check out my repository and build the whole thing in one step. But the boost distribution is some 100MB and thousands of files, and it seems to bog down source control -- plus I really don't need it to be versioned.

What's the best way to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: I would consider option to put these file in source control. Theoretically new version of boost may have changes which are incompatible with your application in some sense. Maybe worth extracting just what you use and put it into vcs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most version control tools/systems provide mechanics to add references to other repositories into your repository.

This way you can keep your repository clean from files of other repositories but still be able to just point to the correct library and version.

In Git it’s called submodules. In SVN it’s called externals.

In the end you’ll have to decide on whether you want to include the files into your repo so others won’t have to checkout the other repos as well, even when the references (submodule/external) make just that pretty easy. I’d prefer a clean repo though and reference other repositories, if available. This will also make maintaining and upgrading those libraries a lot easier.

Comment: Mercurial (the DVCS that I use) doesn't seem to support that feature. :(

Comment: Subrepos seem to be kind of that. Grouping repositories. Not sure if that is really useable for exernals, but should be. On commit will also commit (and on push also push) subrepos first; so not sure. But should work if you're just using externals. http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository

Comment: @Billy hg does have subrepos too. Hg can even interact with svn as remote repo. http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository

Answer (score 0):

I've found the book ["Large-Scale C++ Software Design" by John Lakos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620) very useful as far as organising large C++ projects is concerned. Recommended.

Comment: I hear it is a good book, if outdated a bit. Is there anything specific w.r.t. big library dependencies in there though?

Comment: Can't remember off the top of my head; I will need to look at the book, which I have in my office. I will look at it tomorrow.