# Is there any workaround for hg timing out on a push operation?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I'm trying to push to bitbucket, a changeset with several thousand files which were changed (I'm committing a [huge library dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475968/how-does-one-handle-big-library-dependencies-in-source-control)). The commit on my local box worked just fine, but when I try to do the actual push, the operation times out (`hg` says "searching for changes" for a while, then the whole thing just collapses).

Obviously, I have absolutely no control over the server side.

Anything I can do in a scenario like this?

Comment: what `hg out` said? Also you could try to push partially `hg push changeset_no`, where `changeset_no` is any changeset from the middle of the all changesets need to be pushed.

Comment: @zerkms: 1. Put that in an answer lol. 2. That's strange. Now it says there aren't any changes? Perhaps bitbucket had play with the data for a few mins before it actually worked...

Comment: done. PS: i don't like to guess in an answers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `hg outgoing` say? Also you could try to push partially `hg push -r changeset_no`, where `changeset_no` is any changeset from the middle of the all changesets need to be pushed.

Comment: Understandable. Just wanted to give credit where it was due. Never used `out` before -- I'll keep it in mind. (I'm using TortiseHG most of the time)

Comment: @Billy ONeal: it is also `out` button in TortoiseHG as well http://oi54.tinypic.com/9kv23s.jpg

Comment: That button just caused the UI to hang on my box. Don't think it likes that many files :P

Comment: @Billy ONeal: you may fill a bug then, if you have a little spare time to do it https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/issues?status=new&status=open

Comment: Don't think it's really a bug -- think I was just too impatient :P